# Error while adding iso in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: virtualbox, iso, 13.04

While adding an ISO file to a newly created virtual machine in VirtualBox 4.2.10, the program just stops working, but when I open it again and go again to add the ISO, it's adding OK. When I made another virtual machine it happened again - first time VirtualBox crashed when adding an ISO. Everything happened on an Ubuntu 13.04 host with Gnome Shell.

Comment: Is the ISO already actively in use as a disk in another VM, mounted locally, or still downloading?  That's what it sounds like to me.

Comment: Nope, nothing from those for sure. I use this image on windows for a months, now I change to ubuntu. Moreover it happens with every iso not one specially.

Comment: Is the VM still sitting on an NTFS partition?  If it is move it to a native linux partition in case it's permissions issues.

Comment: That was a solution. I could think about it, damn. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Move the VM to a native linux partition as this is a permissions issue.

Answered by [@RobotHumans](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/robothumans) in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285369/error-while-adding-iso-in-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-13-04#comment358684_285369).